# Getting [Errno 110] 'Connection timed out' when trying to do get requests in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-requests

I am able to access the below "URL" mentioned in code manually in firefox browser and see the json response as :

```
{
  "version" : "1.0",
  "email_address" : "xxxx@emailin.com"
}
```

But when I am trying to do get request with below code I am getting connection timeout error.

```
import requests
URL='https://deviceconfig.pod1.pie.avatar.ext.hp.com/virtualprinter/v1/printers/emailaddress/AQAAAAFiGLv5GQAAAAGrHfgO'
proxies = {'http': '', 'https': ''}
headers={'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:52.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/52.0'}
try:
    r= requests.get(url=URL,proxies=proxies,verify=False,headers=headers)
    print r.status_code
    print r.content
except requests.exceptions.RequestException as e:
    print e.message

Error :
HTTPSConnectionPool(host='deviceconfig.pod1.pie.avatar.ext.hp.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /virtualprinter/v1/printers/emailaddress/AQAAAAFiGLv5GQAAAAGrHfgO (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x7fd9f45080d0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 110] Connection timed out',))
```

Comment: You have a network problem, it could be related to your proxy settings.

Answer (score 4):

Now Get request is working , by setting the proxies with port number.

Added proxy setting in above code:

```
proxies = { 'http': 'web-proxy.xxxxxx.xx.com:8080','https': 'web-proxy.xxxxxx.xx.com:8080'}

Output :
200
{
  "version" : "1.0",
  "email_address" : "xxxx@emailin.com"
}
```